# Odoo issue with button language

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8

I imported a translation in my Odoo 8 but some of the buttons are not changing. They remain in English. 
Here's an example:

[image: Spanish Odoo]

I changed the strings manually by exporting the language and importing it again.
I don't know if that has to be changed in the code itself. 
But each time I upload the language again, it remains the same.

Any helpo would be really appreciated.

Comment: What language you used when you install Odoo? Spanish / Español?

Comment: I used English I think.

Comment: Do you have possibility reinstall Odoo?

Comment: I tried install Odoo with language `Spanish / Español`. And [HERE example](http://prntscr.com/a7tv4s)

Comment: Sorry, I double checked with the guy who made the installation. We installed it in Spanish.
We are positive of that.

Comment: Are you use latest version Odoo? I had the same problem with another language. Try to update Odoo from github. Maybe some translations for Spanish was added later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to updating the base module, and the respective module what you want to generate the translate, in this case account.

Comment: Thank you Juan,
I already did that. After I uploaded the translation, I went to settings and updated the modules list and applied the updates.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Does it work? If it does, you can choose my answer like correct!

Comment: It didn't work actually.
The odd thing is that it changes some buttons but not all of them.

Comment: I know you can speak Spanish like me, but I don't know if Stack Overflow allow it. Anyway, did you Synchronize Terms? Go to Configuration/Translation/Application Terms/Synchronize Terms, and choose the Language what you want to update.

Comment: I think they don't allow other than English to keep it standard for everybody.
I tried that. Didn't know I had to do it. I did it, and the buttons are still in English.

Comment: @AlvaroMoralesSolis please ask this question in the spanish stackoverflow forum http://es.stackoverflow.com/ ,and share the link here to be able to write in Spanish and help you in a better way.

Comment: Thank you Juan, I did. Here it is: 
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5334/odoo-boton-no-cambia-de-idioma